# Table View loading performance issue

Tags: performance, uitableview

I have a UITableView with seven rows each containing text and a .png image. When I add the code to set the image for each row and run the app in the simulator I experience a long loading time.

I suspect that the cause of the performance issue is the fact that my image sizes are too big and I am in the process of scaling my images to the appropriate pixel dimensions. However, I wanted to ensure there is nothing that I could be doing differently in my code to further optimize performance. Is there anything I should be doing differently in my code?

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (!c)
    {
        c = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
//adds text to table view
    [[c textLabel] setText:[categoryNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [[c textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    //add pictures to table view

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[categoryURLs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] ofType:@"png"];
    [[c imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];

    return c;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by resizing images to 44x44 px (standard UITableViewCell height) and 88x88 for the @2x retina images.